# Vue reactivity bug: vue3, vuex4, class components (vuex-class-modules), inversify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vuex4

I'm in the process of upgrading a vue2 project to vue3 which comes with the fun of upgrading most of the dependencies. I'm nearly done with the upgrade, but I am getting some weird bugs with state and vue reactivity.

The issue put simply is that components are not getting updated when computed properties change. If you have 1 store, 1 component, then all works. If you have 2 components, 2 stores, then only 1 component will receive computed property updates the other will not. Each component only needs to interact with its own store.

Each store has properties "items" and "filteredItems". "items" gets set as if it were a response to a network request and "filteredItems" should ideally recompute and notify components when it has changed. The components always get notified when "items" change, but depending on which component is rendered first or second will determine if they get notified on the computed "filteredItems".

Here is the repository for what I believe to be the most basic requirements to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/ThisIsJJones/vue-reactivity-issue

Packages I am using:
"vue": "^3.3.4",
"vuex": "^4.1.0",
"vuex-class-modules": "^1.3.0",
"inversify": "^5.0.1",
"vue-facing-decorator": "^3.0.2",
"typescript": "^4.9.5",

Comment: There's no this.listOfA, shouldn't affect the way it works but there may be other inconsistencies. If the rest of the stack changed somehow, specifically parts that involve TS and Babel, they need attention because this determines how decorators work. I'm not sure you'll be able to get an answer on SO, this is low-profile third-party lib that works in undetermined and hacky ways and no longer supported, so there are very few persons who could know what happens and how to fix it. Based on the internal differences between 2 and 3 I don't see why this could happen. Could be `@Watch` problem too

Comment: I figured, but I thought I'd try. Appreciate the response. 

I've upgraded a dozen packages to work with vue3. It's been a headache to say the least, I'm at the home stretch and this state issue is one of the last things. I'll keep hacking away to see if I can figure something out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the UI was not getting updated from the store changing. The solution was using vuex-facing-decorator.

@Getter('filteredItems', { namespace: 'TestModule' }) filteredItems!: number[];